# PHP print to printer (local / network) directly (stuck in print spooler)

Tags: php, windows, apache, printing, permissions

Ok, I am using PHP 5.4 and I want to print directly from web server to printer.  I am using PHP module php_printer.dll.

The function is work well.  And I see in printer queue, the data is in, but hang in status "sent to printer"

Here is the code

```
        $printerList = printer_list(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL);
        var_dump($printerList);
        $printerName = $printerList[0]['NAME'];
        echo $printerName;
        $printer = $printerName;
        if($ph = printer_open($printer)) {
           $content = "hello";

           // Set print mode to RAW and send PDF to printer
           printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
           printer_write($ph, $content);
           printer_close($ph);
        }
        else "Couldn't connect...";
```

There is no error in screen or logs file in Apache, so i assume the PHP code run well.  And I see the data is in Windows print spooler.  The problem is it stuck in there, and it cannot produce the output from printer.

I assume the problem is because the windows permission problem (I am using windows 8, test in windows 7 or XP cannot work too).  I have 4 test printer: 1. HP Laser Jet 401, 2. PDF Printer, 3. Windows Fax, 4.  XPS document writer.

My computer cannot print to all the 4 printers.  I test in other computer, it can print to printer number 1, but the other cannot.

The status is only "Sent to printer".  If it is printing, the status is "spooling"

I attach the screenshot the queue data in spool printer.  [image: Sent to printer status]

And this is the screenshot that success spooler (I test with print normal, ctrl+p and print) [image: Spooling]

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty certain you can't not go through the spool.  If you could, what would happen if you initiated a print job before the previous one was finished?  You're better off investigating why the print job gets stuck in the spool.

Comment: Hi @GordonM, see my response below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, the problem is you have to add this in the beginning

```
printer_start_doc($ph, "Start Doc");
```

and this before printer_close

```
printer_end_doc($ph);
```

Cannot print without start and end doc.

I am just wondering why I still can print to printer number 1 at other computer, but does not use that start and end doc PHP command.

Comment: Thank you for this! I have a problem with this as well... I will try this if it works. :)

Comment: hi jef! would you mind to share your php_printer.dll , I am looking around internet and I am not getting the correct dll . I am using server windows 7 "wamp" php version ~ 5.4.3  . Please jef.

Comment: Can we print pdf file using this method?

Comment: I am not sure, I tried with one pdf printer can, but the other cannot, theoretically can, but u can try :)